# Things to consider while using session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

While using session in Rails, what are the things that I have to be careful in perspective of security.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good overview in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).

Comment: Very useful link - now favourited

Answer (score 1):

There are vulnerabilities affect sessions regardless of what platform you are using.

[OWASP Top 10 2010 A3-Broken Authentication and Session Management.](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management)